# Differentiable $f: [0, 1] → \mathbb{R}: \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx.$ Prove $\exists c \in (0, 1):f(c) = 2018\int_{0}^{c}f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, rolles-theorem

> $f: [0, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a differentiable function such that $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx.$ Prove that there exists $c \in (0, 1)$ such that $f(c) = 2018\int_{0}^{c}f(x)dx$

**My attempt:**

$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx$

$\iff  \int_{0}^{1}f(x)(x-1)dx = 0 \quad  (*)$

Let $F(x)$ be an antiderivative of $f(x)(x-1)$.

$(*) \iff F(1) - F(0) = 0$

$\iff F(1) - F(0) = F(0) - F(0) = 0$

Let $G(x) = F(x) - F(0) = \int_{0}^{x}f(t)(t-1)dt$ and $H(x) = e^{-2018x}G(x)$

$F(x)$ is differentiable on $[0, 1]$, so $G(x)$ and $H(x)$ are also differentiable on $[0, 1].$

Since $G(1) = G(0) = 0$, we have that $H(0) = H(1) = 0$. By Rolle's theorem,  there exists $c \in (0, 1)$ such that:

$H'(c) = 0$

$\iff -2018e^{-2018c}G(c) + G'(c)e^{-2018c} = 0$

$\iff -2018\int_{0}^{c}f(x)(x - 1)dx + f(c)(c-1) = 0$

$\iff 2018\int_{0}^{c}f(x)dx - f(c) = 2018\int_{0}^{c}xf(x)dx - cf(c)$

At this point, I'm stuck. I need to show that the $LHS = 0$ in order to get the desired outcome, but I have no idea how to proceed, and for some reason it seems I was approaching it the wrong way.

Please advise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$G(x) = e^{-2018x}\int_0^x f(t)dt\quad x\in(0,1)$$
$G$ is differentiable with
$$G'(x)=e^{-2018x}\left(f(x)-2018\int_0^x f(t)dt\right)$$

so the goal is to find a $c\in(0,1)$ such that $G'(c)=0$. Rolle's theorem is a good candidate for that. We already have $G(0)=0$ so we need some $x_1 > 0$ such that $G(x_1)=0$ which is equivalent to $\int_0^{x_1} f(t)dt = 0$. Let's define
$$H(x) = x\int_0^x f(t)dt - \int_0^x tf(t)dt$$
$H$ is differentiable with
$$H'(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$$
so it's enough to find $x_1 \in (0,1)$ such that $H'(x_1)=0$. From the assumption we have $H(0)=H(1)=0$ and so the existence of such $x_1$ is immediate by Rolle's theorem.

Finally, we apply Rolle's theorem again, this time for $G$ in $[0, x_1]$, to get the required $c \in (0, x_1) \subseteq (0, 1)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! Could you please give me some intuition into how to get to a working $H(x)$ like yours? It would be unlikely for me to come up with this $H(x)$ in an exam if I haven't seen a similar problem before. 

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you a "one method to rule them all" type of answer. In this case I defined $H$ in a way that would allow me to use the given assumption.